# Calculating distance between point and MultiPolygon Geoseries object in Python

Tags: python, polygon, distance, shapely, geopandas

I want to calculate the distance of a point from the Multiploygon geoseries object created using `cascaded_union` function of GeoPandas. Following is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.ops import cascaded_union
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Point, MultiPoint

fp = "\\TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3\\TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.shp"
data = gpd.read_file(fp)

mycountries = ['Canada','Russia']

req_data = data[data.NAME.isin(mycountries)]
req_data = req_data.reset_index()
req_data = req_data.drop('index',axis=1)

polygons = [req_data['geometry'][0],req_data['geometry'][1]]
boundary = gpd.GeoSeries(cascaded_union(polygons))
boundary.plot(color = 'black')
plt.show()
```

[image: Result]

I require that when I calculate the distance of two points (as shown on the map: red dots) from the MultiPolygon, it should consider Canada for the one in the left side and Russia for the right one. Also, the distance in miles/km.

I tried using distance function but the result which I am getting is not correct. Moreover, if I consider point somewhere in the Indian Ocean, it gives a result as `0` which is again not what I require.

Shapefile can be downloaded from the TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.zip file available at http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/world_borders.php

Comment: `I tried using distance function` What do you mean? Could you show us what you tried?